# Prediction on GCP with ML Engine

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, google-prediction, census

I am working on GCP to predict, I'm using the census dataset, actually I'm discovering google APIs ( ML Engine ...).

When I launch the prediction job , the job runs successfully, but it doesn't display the result.

Can anyone help ? Do you have any idea why it doesn't generate an output ?

Thanks in advance :)

This is the error that occurs

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9gyTb.png

Comment: I wouldn't say that it runs successfully if it throws an error. Have you verified your model data to be correct?

Comment: Actually that's what was written, take a look at the screenshot,  yes I used the generated model after training.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error is common when you train with one version of TF and then try serving with a lower version. For instance, if you are using Cloud console to deploy your model, it currently has no way of letting you select the version of TensorFlow for serving, so the model is deployed using TF 1.0, but your model may have been trained with a higher version of TF (current version is 1.7).

Although the Cloud console doesn't currently let you select the version (but it will soon!), using `gcloud` or the REST API directly does allow you to.

In the [docs](https://cloud.google.com/ml-engine/docs/tensorflow/deploying-models#creating_a_model_version), there is a section on creating a model that has code snippets under "gcloud" and "python". With gcloud you simply add the argument `--runtime-version=1.6` (or whatever version) and with python you add the property "runtimeVersion": "1.6" to the body of the request.